Ansible Automation Platform - Vault Credentials
Hoping someone can assist.  I have AAP installed and are running a playbook that has a vault encrypted file.  I have a Vault credential set-up via the credential manager and this decrypts the file without issue.  However I wish to use this credential to encrypt another file once it has been downloaded.  I have searched and I think this may not be possible and I would need to use a duplicate locally stored txt file to use for the encryption process but are wondering if anyone has any ideas.  I have tried to use such commands as below to set a fact on the vault password but they all return a blank string
    - name: Write vault password to temporary file
      set_fact:
        vaultpw: "{{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD') }}"
      register: vault_password_result

    - name: Write vault password to temporary file
      set_fact:
        vaultpw: "{{ lookup('env', 'VAULT_PASSWORD') }}"
      register: vault_password_result

Hopefully someone has seen this before ... many thanks!

Ansible uses the vault password to unlock encrypted data when running playbooks. For security reasons, Ansible doesn't share this password as a variable. That's why trying to save the vault password as a fact will always give you an empty result.
There is already a page on here that talks about such things. Give this post a gander: How to get password from ansible vault to be used as variable?

Thanks Heather for the response, thought this would probably be the case.  I wondered as AAP has it as a credential, it could somehow be passed into an encrypt statement.  Not necessarily looking to display it just to use it to encrypt.  Appreciate you taking the time to respond
